# MySQL: select the most recent poster in a forums thread list

Tags: mysql

I have tried many of the similar questions available on Stack, but I find with all of them I continually get the user_name of the wrong user, I am really stuck and have spent the whole day trying to figure this out.

I have a forum, and within the forum is a list of threads, and then within the threads people can post, when a user views the forum, and sees the list of threads, I want them most recent post and the user's name to display

this is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT t.thread_id, t.featured, t.title, t.post_count, t.view_count, t.closed, p.post_id AS latest_reply, if(u2.user_name IS NOT NULL, u2.user_name, u.user_name) AS latest_reply_user_name, MAX(p.timestamp) as timestamp, u.user_name
FROM forum_thread AS t
    LEFT JOIN forum_post AS p ON(t.thread_id = p.thread_id
        AND p.post_id=(SELECT MAX(p.post_id) FROM forum_post WHERE thread_id=p.thread_id))
    LEFT JOIN forum_post as p2 ON (p2.post_id = p.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN user as u ON(t.id = u.id)
    LEFT JOIN user as u2 ON (p2.id = u2.id)
WHERE t.forum_id = :forum_id AND t.sticky=:sticky AND t.removed=0
GROUP BY t.thread_id
ORDER BY latest_reply DESC 
LIMIT :limit_bottom, :limit_top
```

The problem is the u2.user_name appears to be selected randomly and therefore latest_reply_user_name is selected randomly. u2.user_name should be the the user_name of the most recent post.

Comment: If you could create a SQLfiddle with some sample data it would be easier to help.

Comment: Incidentally, this *is* the most frequently asked question on SO under the MySQL tag.

Comment: You don't need `p2`, it's the same as `p`.

Comment: Is `forum_post.id` really the ID of the user, not the ID of the post?

Comment: @Barmar Yes that is correct, it is the id of the user not the post

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery should be:

```
(SELECT MAX(p.post_id) FROM forum_post WHERE thread_id=t.thread_id)
```

so you get the highest post ID in each thread.